# Absolute value quadratic inequalities not the usual?

Tags: inequality, quadratics, absolute-value

$ | -x^2 + 6x | \gt 13 $,for example. I would start off solving $ -x^2 + 6x = \pm 13 $ and either get 4 solutions, 3 solutions or two simply do the the nature of the graph. Without knowing if the two you get are the global minimums of the graph or if they are the two above the local maximum(the middle bump), how could one find out where $ y \gt 13 $?

It seems very hard to do this without a graphing calculator. Is this why I have never seen these types of problems in previous math classes? Due to their impracticality in the classroom and it's constraints(ie: time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, notice that $|-x^2+6x| > 13$ iff $-x^2+6x > 13$ or $-x^2+6x < -13$. Hence, we need to solve these two inequalities and merge the two solutions.

First inequality:

$13 < -x^2+6x$

$x^2-6x+13 < 0$

$(x-3)^2+4 < 0$ (1)

Second inequality:

$-13 > -x^2+6x$

$x^2-6x-13 > 0$

$(x-3)^2-22 > 0$ (2)

For what values of $x$ do inequalities (1) and (2) hold?

Comment: So pretty much just do both inequalities because whether or not y>13 or y<-13 the absolute value function will read it as y>13. I think i was messing up because I was setting them equal to zero and THEN trying to evaluate where > or < and such. So if I initially solve the inequality, it will work out regardless of the curve and where the solutions are?

Comment: Did you mean "y > 13" or "y < -13"? (note the negative sign)

Comment: yes I did mean that

Comment: so is that correct? (the King is impatient)

Comment: $|f(x)| > 13$ iff either $f(x) > 13$ or $f(x) < -13$. This is true regardless of what kind of function $f$ is.

Answer (score 1):

**The Graphical Approach**

You could start off with a bit of simplification $g(x) = |f(x)| = |-x^2 + 6x| = |x(x-6)|$.

Drawing the graph of $f(x) = x(x-6)$ shouldn't be particularly challenging. You know where the roots are (from inspection of the factorised form) and you can simply point-test to see whether each part of the graph ($x<0$, $0<x<6$ and $x>6$) lies above the x-axis or not.

After that, sketch the modulus curve. $|f(x)|$ means that all outputs must become positive, so simply reflect the bottom half of the curve along the x-axis and delete everything underneath it.

Then draw the line $y = 13$. Find the intersections between $g(x)$ and $y=13$ and simply look at the regions for which $g(x) > 13$.

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish between the following two cases:

Case 1: $-x^2+6x \geq 0$

First solve this.  Then the equation, which has to be solved is $-x^2+6x > 13$.

The two solutions I lable $L_{11}$ and $L_{12}$. Then the solution for the first case is  $L_1=L_{11} \wedge L_{12}$

Case 2: $-x^2+6x < 0$

Solve this.  Then the equation, which has to be solved is $x^2-6x > 13$.

Then the solution for the second case is  $L_2=L_{21} \wedge L_{22}$

The solution for the whole equation is $L = L_1 \vee L_2$

Comment: For Case 2: if $x^2 - 6 < 0$, then inequality to be solved is $x^2-6 < -13$ (not $x^2-6 > 13$). Also the problem posted by the OP has $-x^2+6x$ not $-x^2+6$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I corrected my typo. But what is wrong with the inequality in the second case ? I think it is ok to change only the signs on the LHs.

Comment: If $Q < 0$, then $|Q| > 13$ iff $Q < -13$ not $Q > 13$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 But you have $-x^2+6x<-13$ I transform it: $-x^2+6x+13<0\Rightarrow 13<x^2-6x$. That is the same as my $x^2-6x>13$

Comment: In that case, you should have "Case 2: $x^2 - 6x > 0$" not "$x^2 - 6x < 0$". If we are in the case where $x^2 - 6x < 0$, then $x^2 - 6x > 13$ cannot be true.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 The second case has no solution. The solution set is an empty set.

Comment: As currently written, the first case is "$-x^2+6x \ge 0$" and the second case is "$x^2-6x < 0$", i.e. $-x^2+6x > 0$, which overlaps the first case. The values of $x$ for which $x^2-6x > 0$ are not covered in either case.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 That´s the point. I changed the signs in the second case. Thanks for leading me to the fault.