# $\left | -(x+2)^2+6(x+2) \right |>13$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I did $-(x+2)^2+6(x+2)>13$ and $-(x+2)^2+6(x+2)< -13$. The first inequality had complex solutions and therefore can be disregarded but the second one has two real solutions, $x \approx -3.7$ and $5.7$.

So because the graph is negative, we know that to the left and to the right of these two values, all of the $y$ values are $< -13$ so therefore the solution in interval notation is $(-\infty, -3.7) \cup (5.7, \infty)$. I'm not sure my logic is correct in the last part of this. Thank you.

Comment: related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892613/absolute-value-quadratic-inequalities-not-the-usual

Comment: Yep the same method used to solve your other question applies here. Note that you need the exact values for your answer, not approximations.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y = x+2$. Then the inequality becomes $|-y^2+6y| > 13$, which you asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892613) .

Now, just shift all of the intervals to that answer by $2$ to get the answer to this problem.

Comment: +1 for linking to another question and answer by the same asker